# Find the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects arranged in a circular order such that no two consecutive elements are chosen

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, generating-functions

Find the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects arranged in a circular order such that no two consecutive elements are chosen.

I could think of a combinatorial solution-

Arrange the objects such that they are in a row and not in a circular order. To begin with, the objects are arranged as $\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$ (in that order). From the stars and bar method it can be seen that there are a total of ${n-k-1}\choose{k-1}$ ways to choose $k$ objects from the row such that no two are adjacent assuming that object $1$ is chosen. This can be repeated and we can start from all $n$ objects instead of object $1$. But then there's going to be $k$ repeats. And thus the answer gets boiled down to ${\frac{n}{k}} \times {{n-k-1}\choose{k-1}} = \left(\frac{n}{k}\right) {{n-k-1}\choose{k-1}}$.

*I have this solution but then I feel that there are some nice ways using generating functions to solve this. Can anyone help me out?*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not have a generating function approach as well.

Some simple cases:

If $k=0$ , then the solution is $1$.

If $k=1$, then the answer is $n$.

If $k>\frac{n}{2}$, there is no solution.

If $n > 3$ and  $k \le \frac{n}{2}$: We consider $2$ cases.

- Item $1$ is chosen, hence item $n$ and item $2$ are not chosen. We still have to choose $k-1$ items from the remaining $n-3$ items where no adjacent items are chosen. We have $\binom{n-3-(k-1)+1}{k-1}=\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$.
- Item $1$ is not chosen, hence we have to chooose $k$  items from the remaining $n-1$ items. We have $\binom{n-1-k+1}{k}=\binom{n-k}{k}$

Hence the expression should be \begin{align}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-k}{k}&=\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}+\frac{n-k}{k}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\\
&= \frac{n}{k}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\end{align}

Comment: Superb, although have answers here, but none explains like what you have done in a line in final case's first part. See here (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1593653/424260) are five answers to the same, but none explains that part even. Another example of no explanation of your sort is one stated in my answer's reference:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3679784/424260. I got so confused, took $n', k'$. My faulty attempt to answer is an ode to your brevity yet total clarity; and will remain there.

Answer (score 0):

As could gather,  took stars & bars app., & twisted to clr.arrangement. For row, ways of selecting $k$ objects, no two consecutive, from $n$ objects is
${n-k+1\choose k}$, as at:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3679784/424260. Now on, will use modified terms (i.e., $n',k'$) to avoid confusion.

In row based, stars & bars has categories/bars from which to choose as
$n'=k+1$, as have $k+1$ spaces due to $k$ markers; while left stars $k'$ are the leftover elements after taking out $k, k-1$ elements, as for every set of  $k$ objects being picked have to also choose $k-1$:
 So, $n'- k - (k-1)= n' - 2k+1$ objects are left.

$\binom{\left(k+1\right)+\left(n'-2k+1\right)-1}{n'-2k+1}=\binom{n'-k+1}{k}$
with $n'- k+1-(n'-2k+1)= k$

But, clr. arrangement has still $n'=k+1$ markers, but has $k$  in-between spaces (mandatory seperators), instead of $k-1$.
So, the left elements after picking up (or fixing) $k, k$ elements are:
$\binom{\left(k+1\right)+\left(n'-2k\right)-1}{n'-2k}=\binom{n'-k}{k}$
with $n'-k - k' = n'-k-(n'-2k)= k$

You have further assumed that object labelled $1$ is chosen, hence reducing the number of available objects by one.
If accept this then there will be one more object taken out as spacer, leading to a decrease of two.
Hence , need get for the row case expression

Have a doubt here, how to get difference as shown below:
As two elements have been removed, so $n'= k-2$, so further removal of an element for bar, and the accompanying spacer will get :
$n'= k-2, k'=(n')-(k-2)-(k-3)=n'-2k+5$, 
 that will yield :
$\binom{\left(k-2\right)+\left(n'-2k+5\right)-1}{n'-2k+5}=\binom{n'-k+2}{k-3}$
with $n'- k+2-(n'-2k+5)= k-3$

Comment: Are you stating that the OP's solution is incorrect? Are you asking a question or answering a question?

Comment: What have pronouns and complete sentences done to offend you?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thanks for joining. I feel that the solution by author is bit wrong. Author is not clear about row based star-&-bars application's to circular one. Nor he is clear about the modification of removing one element for the circular case. So, unless understood him, cannot pursue further.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am unclear about the author's derivation of formula for circular case. Seems there is so little elaboration that the question simply should have been asked.Also, even the row case has different derivation than elsewhere, as shown in my link to other post.