# Find the number of ways $z_n$ of seating $n$ couples around a rectangular table such that no one is allowed to sit next to his or her partner

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways $z_n$ of seating $n$ couples around a rectangular table such that no one is allowed to sit next to his or her partner.figure $(\text{I})$.

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$[image]
$$\text{Figure (I)}$$
First we should find the number of ways that $2n$ people can sit around the table,we choose $n$ of $2n$ people to sit on one of the sides of the table in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways,besides for the people sitting on each sides of the table there are $n!$ permutations,and so by the multiplicative law:$$\binom{2n}{n}\left(n!\right)^{2}=\left(2n\right)!$$

Denote by $w_k$ the number of seatings under which some specified set of $k$ couples (and possibly some other couples) end up sitting next to their partner:

$$z_n=\left|\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\overline{A_i}\right|=\left(2n\right)!-\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right|=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}w_{k}$$

Now it's left to determine a formula for $w_k$:

This is where I cannot continue,I thought that the formula maybe is :

$$w_k=\binom{2n}{2k}k!\cdot2^{k}\left(2n-2k\right)!$$

(Decide where the k couples go, and which couple goes where, and which partner takes which seat, and where the $2n-2k$ individuals go.)

However after some thought,I figured out that this is not true,since it may happen that one of the husbands/wives be left unpaired,so what is the strategy to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways of forming $k$ non-overlapping pairs of adjacent seats is
$$
\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{n-r}{r}\binom{n-(k-r)}{k-r}.
$$
The two binomial coefficients come from the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667767/number-of-ways-of-selecting-k-objects-no-two-consecutive) applied with parameters $n-1$ and $r$ for the seats on the front side of the table and parameters $n-1$ and $k-r$ for the seats on the back side of the table. The reason for $n-1$ is that the leftmost chair in a pair can't be the rightmost seat in the row.

Using this result and the principle of inclusion-exclusion, the number of arrangements is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}2^k(2n-2k)!\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{n-r}{r}\binom{n-(k-r)}{k-r}.
$$
In this expression, $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ is the number of ways of assigning couples to the chosen pairs of seats, $2^k$ is the number of ways of assigning members of the couples to seats, and $(2n-2k)!$ is the number of ways of assigning the remaining individuals to seats.

For $n=0$, $1$, $2$, $3, \ldots$ the values of this expression are
$$
1,\ 2,\ 16,\ 336,\ 16512,\ 1428480,\ \ldots
$$

Comment: Can you please give me a proof of the first expression,it's totally new to me

Comment: The two binomial factors are just the answer to [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667767/number-of-ways-of-selecting-k-objects-no-two-consecutive) applied with parameters $n-1$ and $r$ for the bottom side of the table and parameters $n-1$ and $k-r$ for the top side of the table. The reason for $n-1$ is that the leftmost chair in a pair can't be the rightmost seat in the row.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations.I think before permuting the remaining $2n-2nk$ individuals,we need to select them,since we choose $r$ vertices from on of the sides of the table,hence $n-2r$ vertices has left,and we need to choose $n-2r$ individuals from the $2n-2k$ people to sit there,this can be done in $\binom{2n-2k}{n-2r}$ ways,the other $n-2k+2r$ individuals should sit on the other side of the table,besides this unpaired people on the both sides have $\left(n-2r\right)!\left(n-2k+2r\right)!$ permutations,so I think the formula is ....:

Comment: $$\sum_{r=0}^{k}\binom{n-r}{r}\binom{n-(k-r)}{k-r}\binom{2n-2k}{n-2r}\left(n-2r\right)!\left(n-2k+2r\right)!$$

$$\left(2n-2k\right)!\sum_{r=0}^{k}\binom{n-r}{r}\binom{n-(k-r)}{k-r}$$ Which is what you said,I was just a little confusing about the process,it seems 
convincing to **first select** which people are going to sit on which sides of the table and **then permuting** them,instead of permuting them **directly**,both ways gives the same answer,however I think you already have done my process and then you typed the simplified form.

Comment: But permuting them without first selecting them does not seem correct (If I'm wrong please let me know).

Comment: Well, $_nP_r=r!\,_nC_r$, so it's all the same. In other words, you can either write $\frac{n!}{(n-r)}$ or you can write $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}r!$. I think of $_nP_r=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ as the number of ways of filling $r$ slots with items chosen from a set of size $n$,so I usually just go directly to that expression.