# If k integers are selected at random and without replacement from 1 to 100 what is the probability that any of the integers are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand the denominator would be 100 choose k, but I don't understand how to calculate the # of combinations which have any adjacent integers.

I remember the basics of probability and combinatorics from a college level statistics class from over 5 years ago, but many of the details escape me. I'm trying to figure out the probability of an event in a card game and I've condensed the most difficult part of the problem to the above statement.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Could you edit your question to tell us a bit about your mathematics background?  What have you learned about combinatorics so far?

Comment: This is a Stars and Bars problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see 
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Consider the number of solutions to $$x_1 + \cdots + x_{k+1} = 100 - k ~: ~x_1,x_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~x_2, \cdots,x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$$  The idea is that the $k$ selected numbers form $(k+1)$ **gaps**, each of whose size is assigned a variable.  All of the gaps except the very first and very last must be $~\geq 1.$

Comment: Per previous comment, the # of solutions will provide the *numerator* to the **complementary event** (i.e. none of the integers are adjacent to each other).

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree with the negative reactions to this posting.  I don't see any reasonable line of attack except Stars and Bars (or perhaps generating functions, which I am ignorant of).  Stars and Bars theory is so obscure that I feel that it is not reasonable to expect the OP (i.e. original poster) to *show work* for this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post.  My recommendation is that you subtract the probability that no two of the numbers are adjacent from $1$.

Comment: See [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667767/number-of-ways-of-selecting-k-objects-no-two-consecutive) for more approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating the ideas in my comments, and answering the question:

> If k integers are selected at random and without replacement from 1 to 100 what is the probability that any of the integers are adjacent?

I will express the probability as

$$1 - \frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{100}{k},$$

where $N$ refers to the number of solutions to:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k + x_{k+1} = 100 - k.$
- $x_1, x_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$
- $x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

With $~\dfrac{N}{D}~$ denoting the complementary probability, $~N~$ needs to represent the total number of ways of selecting $k$ (random) integers, from the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ such that no two of the selected integers are adjacent.

As indicated by my comments, the idea is that the $k$ selected integers create $(k+1)$ **gaps** between the **unselected** elements in $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ with the sum of these gaps totaling $(100 - k).$

Clearly, each of the variables $~x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{k+1}~$ needs to be a non-negative integer, to validly represent the gap between any two of the selected integers.

The first and last gap, which are represented by $~x_1~$ and $~x_{k+1}~$ are allowed to equal $~0,~$ since these gaps represent the gap before the very first selected integer and after the very last (i.e. the $k$-th) selected integer.

For example, $~x_1 = 0~$ corresponds to the first selected integer equaling "1", while $~x_{k+1} = 0~$ corresponds to the last selected integer equaling "100".

Then, the constraint that no two of the selected integers are *adjacent* (i.e. consecutive numbers) will be satisfied **if and only if** each of $~x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_k~$ is $~\geq 1.$

---

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Basic Stars and Bars theory indicates that the number of solutions to:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n, ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_r \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$

is $~\displaystyle \binom{n + [r-1]}{r-1}.$

The given problem may be easily transformed into the basic format by the change of variable:

$y_i = x_i - 1, ~i \in \{2,3,\cdots,k\}.$

This transforms the enumeration of $N$ into counting the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + \cdots + y_k + x_{k+1} = 100 - k - (k-1) = 101-2k.$
- $x_1, x_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$
- $y_2, y_3, \cdots, y_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory:

$$N = \binom{[101-2k] + k}{k} = \binom{101 - k}{k}. \tag1 $$

The RHS of (1) above may be **moderately** sanity-checked.

- If $~k > 50,~$ there are no solutions, so $~N = 0.$
- For $~k = 50,~$ the $~51~$ solutions correspond to starting with the selection $~\{1,3,5,\cdots,99\},~$ and then (**optionally**) selecting one of the $50$ (odd) selected elements, and incrementing each element from *that point to the end* by $1$.

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

The desired probability is

$$1 - \frac{N}{D} = 1 - \frac{\binom{101 - k}{k}}{\binom{100}{k}} = 1 - \frac{[(101 - k)!] \times [(100 - k)!]}{[(101 - 2k)!] \times [(100)!]}.$$

Comment: Ah, I got stuck transforming the equation you had into what you call the basic star and bars format without the conditions. It makes sense that you can do that. Thank you for the resources, going to take a bit to fully wrap my head around it. 

It's been too long since I've done problems like these...

Comment: @DTDynasty Now that you have comprehended my answer, it is well worth your while to study the (more elegant) answer of true blue anil, where $~n=10,k=4.$  In his analysis, the $(k=4)$ tokens represent the (4 out of 7) locations that you choose to create the 4 **gaps**.  His  computation of the *complementary numerator* can be re-expressed as $~\displaystyle \binom{[10 + 1] - 4}{4},~$ which analogizes to my computation of $~\displaystyle \binom{[100 + 1] - k}{k}.$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to select $4$ tokens from $10\;\rightarrow \binom {10}4= 210$ ways

- Take out those $4$ tokens, $6$ remain with $7$ interstices shown by uparrows $\uparrow\,\bullet\uparrow\,\bullet\uparrow\,\bullet\uparrow\,\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow$
- Insert back the $4$ tokens in $\binom74 = 35$ non-adjacent ways
- P(Tokens with at least two adjacent  members) $= 1 - \frac{35}{210}$

It follows that for the general case of choosing $k$ integers from $n$

P(any of the integers are adjacent) $=1 - \dfrac{\dbinom{n-k+1}{k}}{\dbinom{n}{k}}$

Comment: +1 : Nice shortcut.

Comment: @user2661923: Thanks, yours is a model of thoroughness, as usual. Btw, I am also a  fan of stars and bars. Cheers ! (+1)