# Confusion with regards to the selection of 4 objects from this sequence

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So my post is regarding the accepted answer written by Will Orrick (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3736/will-orrick), Number of ways of selecting k objects, no two consecutive, URL (version: 2020-05-17): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3679784

Please make sure to go through that post.

Now Will has written:

> All that is needed is to count star-and-bar sequences. The first three bars are always followed by a star—there is no choice in the matter—so we absorb each of these "mandatory" stars into the adjacent bar. With this change the sequence corresponding to $\{2,4,7,10\}$ becomes $*|\,|*|*|$, while the sequence corresponding to $\{1,3,5,7\}$ becomes $|\,|\,|\,|***$. **Each sequence now consists of four bars and three stars, and there are $\binom{4+3}{4}$ such sequences**.

Could someone explain why we use combination (in the line I highlighted in bold in Will's answer) to count the number of sequences? Moreover I couldn't understand the intention there. **Could you please explain the significance of the highlighted line?**

What I thought was happening here is that since we have 3 stars remaining in $|\,|\,|\,|***$, our main intention is find the number of ways by which we can place these stars inside or outside the "bins" (*as quoted by Will in his answer*) as in this case the bins can assume a possibility of being empty *(as the initial minimum condition of at least 1 star in between is already satisfied)* **Is my understanding correct?**

I think maybe my confusion exists is because I actually don't understand the total number of ways by which (note that this isn't with regards to Will's answer) 3 stars can be placed with respect to 3 horizontal lines ||| in such a way that the "bins" (space/gap between any two vertical lines) can remain empty.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways you can arrange four indistinguishable sticks and three indistinguishable stones is
$$\binom{4 + 3}{4} = \binom{4 + 3}{3}$$
since the sequence of sticks and stones is completely determined by choosing which four of the seven positions will be occupied by sticks or, equivalently, which three of the seven positions will be occupied by stones.

The underlying idea in Will Orrick's argument is to create a bijection between selections of four objects from $10$ objects in which no two selected objects are consecutive and selections of four objects from seven objects.

Let's start with seven balls, each of a different color, lined up in a row.  We can select any four of the seven balls in $\binom{7}{4}$ ways.  If we now insert a white ball to the right of each of the first three selected balls, we will ensure that no two of the selected balls will be consecutive in our new arrangement.  If we were to now number the $10$ balls from left to right, no two of the numbers on the balls we originally selected would be consecutive.  Hence, there are $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to select four numbers from the first ten positive integers so that no two of the selected numbers are consecutive.

In Will's argument, he started with $10$ numbers, selected four of them so that no two are consecutive, removed the three numbers that were to the immediate right of the first three selected numbers since none of those balls could be among the selections, and argued that, consequently, the number of selections of four numbers from $10$ numbers in which no two selections are consecutive is equivalent to the number of selections of four numbers from seven numbers.  Essentially, he removed the three balls that I inserted in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Great just 1 last doubt:  "The number of ways you can arrange four **indistinguishable** sticks and three **indistinguishable** stones is"....here if instead it was **distinguishable**....then the formula would have been $$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$? But when indistinguishable then $$\frac{n!}{r!×(n-r)!}$$

Comment: (continuation to above comment)....which can also be written as $$\binom{n}{r}$$

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman  If the $n$ objects were distinct, they could be arranged in $n!$ ways.   Note that we could still choose $k$ of the $n$ positions for the distinct sticks in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, arrange the sticks in those $k$ positions in $k!$ ways, and arrange the distinct stones in the remaining $n - k$ positions in $(n - k)!$ ways, giving $\binom{n}{k}k!(n - k)! = n!$ possible arrangements.